# Ckeditor, как настроить на загрузку файлов на сервер?

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

Не получается получить изображение в админке. Загружаю файл через панель
(image propreties>uploads>..)
На сервере создается папка media/uploads/../../файл, следовательно конфиги должны быть правильными, только вот ckeditor достать не может потом.

Логи:

```
2016-03-12T12:54:24.886403+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/ckeditor/upload/?CKEditor=id_text&CKEditorFuncNum=0&langCode=en" request_id=4e200509-ad7b-4c12-b241-c4178848b034 fwd="5.18.179.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=417ms status=200 bytes=383

2016-03-12T12:54:25.206360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/media/uploads/2016/03/12/jnmhymrjbba.jpg" request_id=d44af94e-bacc-45bf-823a-15a0379e65b9 fwd="5.18.179.250" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=28ms status=404 bytes=2233

2016-03-12T12:54:25.376465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono/images/lock-open.png" request_id=144e69b4-2daa-49c3-a327-c2bd95ce9fbf fwd="5.18.179.250" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=110

2016-03-12T12:54:25.379924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/image/images/noimage.png?t=F7OI"  request_id=cb724f70-fd08-4e19-a3fc-beec3a68cbb8 fwd="5.18.179.250" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=110
```

`requirements.txt` :

```
Django==1.9.2
django-ckeditor==5.0.3
gunicorn==19.4.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
Pillow==3.1.1
...
```

`settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'article/static/static_root')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL =    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
"default": {
    "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
    'allowedContent': True,
    'toolbar_Full': [
    ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ],
    ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
    ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
    ['Smiley','sourcearea', 'SpecialChar'],
    [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ],
    [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ],
    [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ],
    [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
    [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ],
    [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ]
], }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась, изменил в settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```